# Invoke-Webrequest does not POST login form

Tags: powershell, post, http-headers, http-post, httpwebrequest

I am trying to obtain some info on a local webpage which requires a login to access.

I can run

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest "http://web.com/admin/launch?script=rh&template=dashboard" -SessionVariable rb -UserAgent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'
```

`$response` contains the correct information, including a single form called `login_form` which I need to use.

Then, I write:

```
$response.Forms[0].Fields.user_id = 'admin'
$response.Forms[0].Fields.password= 'pass'
$response.Forms[0].Fields

Key       Value  
---       -----  
d_user_id user_id
t_user_id string 
c_user_id string 
e_user_id true   
user_id   admin  
password  pass
```

I would expect the following command to return the data of the page which I am redirected to after login.

```
Invoke-WebRequest $('http://web.com/admin/' + $response.Forms[0].Action) -WebSession $rb -Body $response.Forms[0].Fields -Method POST -contentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

**However, this simply re-returns the previous page, including the `login_form` object. It is identical to `$response` even though the request seems to be completely different.**

I think this issue spawns from the same URL being used for every page, with different Query String Parameters (e.g. `script=rh&template=login&action=login`) returning different pages. However, I do include these strings in my `-URI` param, in the form of the string or the `Action` property. Thus I am not sure what other method I would use to return the correct page, if my POST request is even working at all.

I'm completely stuck here, with the absence of any error to work off. I do not think I have made any error with the Request as I have spent a long time tweaking parameters (different syntax for defining the fields, and etc), which has made no difference.

Chrome HAR File: [Google Drive Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ul1MvY_e3NVlO-XEMsLjx9TAhqCqaVhG/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Are you trying to do this strictly "in-console" or would creating a browser session with IE be acceptable?  Something like `$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible= $true`

Comment: @BryceMcDonald This does need to be in-console unfortunately.

Comment: How are you able to "log in" successfully? You're just grabbing the response. I don't see any authentication? You are not logged in, it seems?

Comment: @AussieJoe I am submitting a post to the action URI with a body including the correct fields for login (user, pass). This is identical to a number of tutorials I have read on the subject.

Comment: I don't think you're authenticated, as you keep getting the login page response. That indicates you don't have a token (security) for subsequent requests. Have you inspected the login credentials you are providing via the form?

Comment: Yes and they seem to match those I observed via Chrome dev tools. You can see in my question the table I submit - those are identical to what I would post through Chrome. @AussieJoe

Comment: Have you tried https?

Comment: @AussieJoe The website does not support SSL. It's an internal page

Comment: Please provide the `har` file of the complete interaction from chrome. You may be missing something. I would also look at http://www.powershellcookbook.com/recipe/vODQ/script-a-web-application-session to see handling cookies as well

Comment: @TarunLalwani Is there a particular part of the file you are interested in? This file includes a lot of data and I would have to censor it.

Comment: mostly to see how the login interaction happens

Comment: @TarunLalwani Alright I believe I have a file that demonstrates the process fairly well, I just clipped out sensitive info and requests after authentication (random css and etc). File services are blocked at my office but I can upload it in an hour or so. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TarunLalwani I put a link at the bottom of my post

Comment: Is this an actual website or some appliance login page?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 It is a front-end for an appliance, but it is an "actual website" as well.

Comment: Invoke-WebRequest h t t p : / / removed/admin/launch?script=rh&template=login&action=login also, id suggest, forget ie coms/hars etc, use Fiddler and try to replicate the request 'manually' - headers, body etc -- no form dot smth etc

meaning, for a start, your Uri doesnt seem to match

Comment: Could you please try with complete Form, rather than the fields array alone. $response.Forms[0] - and also could you please confirm that , posting same data from postman (or similar) application will work ?

Comment: Posting the complete form does not seem to make a difference. I tried to replicate in Fiddler - I can get it to work but I have to copy my session variable. I guess this could be the reason I am having issues, maybe that information is just not being put into the SessionVariable. In Fiddler it wasn't returning this info at all even though it seems like I was authenticating, so I was just getting directed right back to the login page (identical behavior as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. There were additional fields that the form needed. There was JS running to re-name the fields in the form, and thus when I was getting the login object I was populating the "wrong" fields since Invoke-Webrequest does not run the JS when I post the form, of course. After playing with the request with Fiddler for a long time, I eventually noticed that a successful login was the result of these fields that were named ever-so-slightly differently. This is how it ended up looking:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest "http://web.com/admin/launch?script=rh&template=login" -SessionVariable x -UserAgent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'

$response.Forms[0].Fields.Add('f_user_id','admin')
$response.Forms[0].Fields.Add('f_password','')

$null = Invoke-WebRequest $('http://web.com/admin/' + $response.Forms[0].Action) -WebSession $x -Body $response.Forms[0].Fields -Method POST -contentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Invoke-WebRequest 'http://web.com/admin/launch?script=rh&template=dashboard' -WebSession $x
```